# Ranking Algorithm - Keeping Score Column Up to Date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ranking

I'm using `Rails` and `PostgreSQL` to implement a `ranking` and `sorting` functionality like `Reddit`, `Hackernews`, etc.. (out of my comfort zone for context)

I have a `ranking algorithm` which is based on `submission time` and `number of upvotes`. The algorithm is in my `Post Model`.

Right now I have it run each time there's an upvote or a new post is created.

The problem I'm running into is that, I need to keep the `score attribute` (generated by the ranking algorithm) in my `Post Model` up to date (since it's affected by time since submission).

What's the best way to constantly be updating the score of each record?

Essentially, I need to run each post through the algorithm before they're sorted and returned to the controller.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: It sounds like you have to calculate it on-the-fly when data is retrieved from the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there way to keep the column in the database up to date? I've implemented pagination and the default scope in my post model is to order based on score. It seems inefficient to have to load all my post records on the fly and then rank them again and write that score back to the database

Comment: . . It seems like the ranking algorithm should be entirely implemented inside the database.

Comment: I need more detail but I think after submission and each upvote you have to calculate score and then where ever you want to show the data the query should be sort the records based on score.What's the problem exactly ? :)